# How to smart read PDF files in android on a mobile screen?

Tags: pdf, ebook-reader

I have a large PDF file in my phone that I want to read while in transit. I have the adobe app downloaded for this purpose but there is no smart read feature in it. I do not want to scroll the screen horizontally. Is there an app that I can use to do this?

[Edit]
I do not want the app to read it aloud for me. I just want to scroll vertically by myself with the contents of the file fitting the screen and the words still readable.

Comment: What is smart read? Do you want the app to read aloud the text in pdf? or you want to scroll the pdf vertically by yourself?

Comment: Hi! Questions asking us app suggestion/recommendation are off-topic here. See [help/on-topic] to know more. Since the title is on-topic I recommend an edit to remove the off-topic part from body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@Voice Read Aloud](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hyperionics.avar) app from the Play Store. Using @Voice Read Aloud app you can read aloud the text displayed in Android apps, e.g. web pages, news articles, long emails, TXT, PDF, DOC, DOCX, RTF, OpenOffice document files and more.

***Note:*** You need [Text-To-Speech engine and voices](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tts) installed on your device to use this app. You may use more than one if you want.